# Tensorflow2 not working on Ubuntu 18.04. Probably incorrect installation, but what?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-18.04, tensorflow2.0

I installed Tensorflow2.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with cuda 10.1, cudnn7.6.5.32, Nvidia driver 430.5.

I could not follow the instructions on the tensorflow site properly as many parts do not work, but, after many hours, I did finally get all the components installed.  When I try to run a 20 line mnist example I get:

```
2020-02-19 03:02:24.915143: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.683GHz coreCount: 28 deviceMemorySize: 10.91GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 451.17GiB/s
2020-02-19 03:02:24.915194: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-02-19 03:02:24.915216: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-02-19 03:02:24.915234: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-02-19 03:02:24.915253: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-02-19 03:02:24.915271: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-02-19 03:02:24.915289: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-02-19 03:02:24.915308: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-02-19 03:02:24.917997: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-02-19 03:02:24.918060: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-02-19 03:02:24.920974: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-02-19 03:02:24.921000: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-02-19 03:02:24.921013: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-02-19 03:02:24.924091: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10258 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Train on 60000 samples
Epoch 1/5
2020-02-19 03:02:26.155747: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-02-19 03:02:26.156063: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:238] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2020-02-19 03:02:26.156110: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:238] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2020-02-19 03:02:26.156225: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:238] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2020-02-19 03:02:26.156253: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:238] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2020-02-19 03:02:26.156483: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:238] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2020-02-19 03:02:26.158110: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:238] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2020-02-19 03:02:26.158133: W tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:2041] attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support
2020-02-19 03:02:26.158158: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(32, 784), b.shape=(784, 128), m=32, n=128, k=784
     [[{{node sequential/dense/MatMul}}]]
```

I understand that this error probably means there is an error in the installation, but how can I determine what ?  Is there ANY way to determine which version of cudnn is used ?

I have googled extensively and there are loads of people with the same problem, but no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days trying to get this rubbish to work.  In the end I'll never know why it finally started to work.  I now know that everything I did was correct in principle but, although the install apparently worked, a simple mnist example failed with CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED.

When I finally got it to work, I:

- Removed every Cuda related package before I started.
- Followed the procedure [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-on-ubuntu-18-04-1c1d2d6d6fd2).  It is way clearer than the official docs.
- At step 4) installing cuda 10.1 I executed:

  sudo apt-get install cuda-10-1

  instead of:

  sudo apt-get install cuda

This ensures that cuda is not automatically upgrade to the most recent version (10.2) at time of writing.